# node mysql insert to many to many table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using nodejs to parse a csv file and save information about it in mysql. I'm trying to insert data to a many to many table but want the id's inserted to the database to be used in a anohter query?

```
con.query("INSERT INTO TransactionDescription SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Description= VALUES(Description)", trandesc, function(err, res) {
                            if (err) throw err;


                        });
```

can i return the id's generated so i can use them in this query ?

```
  con.query("INSERT INTO Transaction SET ? ", tran, function(err, res) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                        });
```

Comment: As a note, `transaction` is not a very good name for a table since it's a reserved keyword. Don't forget `LOAD DATA INFILE` can handle CSV data directly, it's very fast.

Comment: Its probably going to be stored in the `res` object of your callback. Have you `console.log(res)` to see what that contains? Also, it'd be useful to know what the `con` object is, is it a node-mysql? or and instance of some other module.

Comment: @theatlasroom con is connection object in  node-mysq and  yes res returns all id inserted but i want to use those inserted id in a anohter query

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), you can simply get the inserted id like this ([see doc](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row)) :

```
con.query("INSERT INTO TransactionDescription SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Description= VALUES(Description)", trandesc, function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // res.insertId from above query as second query parameter
  con.query("INSERT INTO Transaction SET ? ", res.insertId, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Comment: my problem is that the inserts are a part of different events

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) which simplifies writing queries a lot. Also it easily allows you to access the generated id's, e.g.

```
knex.insert({
  first_name: firstName,
  last_name: lastName,
  email: email,
  phone_number: phoneNumber
})
.returning('id')
.into('person')
.then(function (id) {
  // use id here
});
```